# Android onOptionsItemSelected method of Fragment doesn't get called

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-actionbaractivity

there are many questions about the topic but i can't figure out my problem. I have a menu declared in my `MainActivity`(`ActionBarActivity`). Now i want to work with `MenuItem` in `onOptionsItemSelected` of a `Fragment` class. Here is my `MainActivity` methods

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.add_note:
            createNewNote();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void createNewNote() {
    Intent addIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddNote.class);
    startActivity(addIntent);
}
```

And `Fragment` methods

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.add_note:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Entered into fragment", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            createNewNote();
            return true;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void createNewNote() {

    Intent addIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddNote.class);
    startActivity(addIntent);
}
```

Here in `MainActivity onOptionsItemSelected` get called even in `Fragment` but doesn't in `Fragment` as i don't see `Toast` in `Fragment`. I think something is missed in my code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside `onOptionsItemSelected()` in activity inside your switch after calling `createNewNote()` instead of returning `true` return `super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)`

Answer (score 0):

you must call `setHasOptionsMenu()` inside `onCreate` of fragment for menu related method to work.

Comment: see my `Fragment` code, i added `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` inside `onCreate` of fragment class

Answer (score 0):

Your `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method does not inflate the menu file:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```